# I have two CKEditor in same page. I want to hide one of them. How can I do that?

Tags: jquery, django, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor with Jquery plugin. I have 2 editors displayed when the HTML page is loading. I just need 1 editor to be displayed and want to hide one(Ckeditor).

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form.sms-comm-template').on('submit', function (elem) {
                elem.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    type: $(this).attr('method'),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#comm-update').css({'display': 'none'});
                        $('#Communication').css({'display': 'block'});
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                        $('.template_body').each(function(e){
                            CKEDITOR.replace( this.id,                                
                                { scayt_autoStartup : true, },
                                display: none,);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, err) {
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I believe some additional information would be helpful to get answers, e.g. what are you trying to achieve (why are you sending an Ajax request to hide a form?) and your HTML template

Comment: When you say "hide one" do you actually mean prevent it from happening?

Comment: Yes,correct. I realized that the issue is with java script and resolved the issue.